# Third Party Components with TDD

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

Am trying to get started using TDD on a class which spits out an object belonging to a third party component. However am getting a bit confused in that apparently:

a) With unit tests objects should be tested in isolation

b) Third-party components should be wrapped into an adapter

Do these rules apply when writing tests for code which returns an instance of an object belonging to a third party component? As an example, here's the test so far:

```
// Arrange
string foodXml = "<food><ingredient>Cabbages</ingredient>" +
                 "<ingredient>Bananas</ingredient></food>";
IFoodMixer mixer = new FoodMixer();

// Act

// Smoothie is the third-party component object
Smoothie urgh = mixer.Mix(foodXml);

// Assert

Assert.AreEquals("Cabbages", urgh.Ingredients[0].Name);
Assert.AreEquals("Bananas", urgh.Ingredients[1].Name);
```

Apologies if this question seems a bit basic (or if the concept above seems a tad silly!) - am just struggling to understand how the two rules above could apply in this situation.

Thanks in advance for any advice given!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would be practical with it. If Smoothie is just a data object, don't bother wrapping it.

There's something inside that FoodMixer which is creating the Smoothie in the first place. If that's a 3rd party component, I would wrap it up (you can delegate from a class to a static method if required), then dependency-inject the wrapper and mock it out in your unit test.

Your unit test is then describing the behaviour and responsibilities of your FoodMixer, independently of the SmoothieMaker (whether it's 3rd-party or otherwise). Part of the FoodMixer's responsibility is to ask the SmoothieMaker for a Smoothie, not to actually make the Smoothie itself. By mocking it out we can express that responsibility and class scope.

If your Smoothie is not just a data object but has rich behaviour, I would wrap that within your wrapped SmoothieMaker too.

Now you are completely decoupled from your 3rd party libraries, and you can unit-test easily as a useful by-product.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed response! Problem is the Smoothie object is quite complex and FoodMixer is likely to be using much of its functionality (its NPOI btw for producing Excel files). Should it still be wrapped? Feels like it would involve rewriting much of it.

Comment: In this case I would work out what you want to achieve, add a wrapper which does those things, then put NPOI inside it. It doesn't have to be a one-to-one delegation. You don't need to unit test the wrapper itself if it's either simple enough to test by inspection, or you're testing it manually and it's not going to change (because unit-testing isn't really about testing, it's about making things easy to change).

Comment: I fully appreciate your responses and that having an adapter for NPOI would be the correct and proper way to approach this, just that it seems like a massive amount of effort given the XML will ultimately specify so many characteristics of the NPOI object to the point where it will almost be a serialised representation of it. Therefore to get started I'll probably return an instance of the object first and check its properties in the test, then look into writing/replacing it with an adapter later if possible.

Answer (score -1):

Look at mockito as a simpler way to create mocks automatically and verify assertions instead of using adapters.
There are also many good tutorial on mockito (and JMocks) that are also good TDD tutorials.

Comment: You still need to create an adapter for many 3rd party classes, if they have for instance static methods, get created privately by other classes, etc. - otherwise you can't mock them out. Also writer has tagged this C#, and Mockito and JMock are both Java libraries (use Moq for C#)!

Comment: mmmh, yes it's true I replied for Java, but you don't need the adapters with mock objects. I assumed the same was valid for .net

Comment: Fraid not. No CgLib for .NET - all methods have to either come from an interface or be virtual (we can't even mock classes in .NET except for virtual methods). Also the mocking isn't really the point -  it's decoupling yourself from 3rd party libraries, which you won't do efficiently if you're trapped in their API.